# Why is SPOOL COMMAND not working in RHEL?

Tags: oracle, shell

I have a few shell scripts where they have spool command of the oracle. But it is not working in RHEL 7. In RHEL we have Oracle SQL Client 12.2. But previously I had OpenSUSE OS and Oracle SQL Client 11.2 and there it was working fine. I am using this way

```
cd $ORACLE_HOME
./sqlplus -S "$USERNAME"/"$PASSWD"@"$DB" << EOF >> $LOGFILE
SET ECHO OFF
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SPOOL $DIR/user.csv
SELECT * FROM PBR_OWNER.PSRS_USER;
SPOOL OFF
```

In user.csv no data is coming. Please help what to do.

Comment: Are you sure `$DIR` is pointing where you think - does the timestamp on the csv file you're looking at change when you run this script? And - just to rule out the painfully obvious - does your query actually return rows when you run it; and does the log file say anything relevent?

Comment: Aside from your output issue (which I agree is probably because `$DIR` isn't set), I see your filename is `user.csv`.  Why not use SQL\*Plus 12.2 `SET MARKUP CSV ON` mode to create an actual CSV file? See [Fast Generation of CSV and JSON from Oracle Database](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/fast-generation-of-csv-and-json-from-oracle-database).

Answer (score 0):

If all variables are correctly set and Oracle Net connection to "$DB" works  your script should work:

```
DIR=/tmp
USERNAME=system
PASSWD=oracle
DB=NCDB
LOGFILE=/tmp/ts.log
#
sqlplus -S "$USERNAME"/"$PASSWD"@"$DB" << EOF >> $LOGFILE
SET ECHO OFF
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SPOOL $DIR/user.csv
SELECT * FROM t;
SPOOL OFF
EOF
#
cat $DIR/user.csv
```

With:

```
SQL> show user;
USER est "SYSTEM"
SQL> select * from t;

X
----------
OK

SQL>
```

I get:

```
$ ./ts.sh

OK                                                                              
$ cat /tmp/user.csv

OK                                                                              
$
```